# XNA 2D World reflection on x-axis

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, transform

I'm trying to reflect my game world on the x-axis.
I have a camera, which calculate transform matrix:

```
        _transform =
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_pos.X, -_pos.Y, 0)) *                        
                    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *                        
                    Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom) *
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(_graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.5f, _graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.5f, 0));
```

It works fine, until I put a reflection part:

```
        _transform = //first try, place here
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_pos.X, -_pos.Y, 0)) *                        
                    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *                        
                    Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom) *
                    Matrix.CreateReflection(new Plane(Vector3.UnitY, 0)) * //here
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(_graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.5f, _graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.5f, 0));
```

With that "reflection"

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront,
                    BlendState.AlphaBlend,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    Camera.Active.GetTransformation);
```

draw nothing.
Please, help and sorry for my english :)

---

**UPD**: I have made some tests:

```
var v = new Vector2(0, 10);
var v2 = Vector2.Transform(v, _transform);
```

without .CreateReflection  v2 = {X:450 Y:370}
with .CreateReflection v2 = {X:450 Y:350} //okay. it's reflected. but, why it dont drawing?

Comment: Are you drawing primitives or sprites?

Comment: Can you copy the code you use to draw a sprite normally and the same sprite relflected?

Comment: See comment under 1 answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a scale with the X negated should do the job:

```
    _transform = //first try, place here
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_pos.X, -_pos.Y, 0)) *                        
                Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *                        
                Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom) *
                Matrix.CreateScale(-1,1,1) * //here
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(_graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.5f, _graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.5f, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, for good idea, but it not solved my problem.
What I do wrong?
In Game.Update() I call
`Camera.Active.Update(gameTime); //(where _transform calculates)`
In Game.Draw() I call
`spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront,
                        BlendState.AlphaBlend,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        Camera.Active.GetTransformation);
            foreach (var body in bodies)
                spriteBatch.DrawCircle(body.Position, Radius, 20, Color);`

Comment: May be problem in DrawCircle extension? It use: 
`spriteBatch.Draw(pixel,
                             point,
                             null,
                             color,
                             angle,
                             Vector2.Zero,
                             new Vector2(length, thickness),
                             SpriteEffects.None,
                             0);`

Comment: You have to sure that every spritebatch.Begin call its done with the camera transform as argument... without watching more code or screen captures with the problem, I can't figure what to solve

Comment: aaahhh... I have edited the answerr to make Scale = (-1,1,1) not (-1,0,0) that was very wrong ...

Comment: I know about (-1, 1, 1), it not working too for me.
Have a look at all code, please:
[http://pastie.org/8277503](http://pastie.org/8277503)
(it's too large for posting here)

Comment: hmm. maybe the reflection inverts the sprite and it becomes invisible for the user (like 3D triangle with )?
screenshots: [without scale (1, -1, 1)](http://i018.radikal.ru/1308/1d/6141e3175387.png) [with scale (1, -1, 1)](http://s020.radikal.ru/i721/1308/7e/09364f7bbbc0.png)
cursor placed is right top window corner in both cases

Comment: You have to add RasterizerState.CullNone to the spritebatch.Begin